# Cannot plot candlestick data from Huobi json data

Tags: json, python-3.x, date, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt
import urllib
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
import datetime as dt
import requests

dataLink ='http://api.huobi.com/staticmarket/btc_kline_015_json.js'
r = requests.get(dataLink)  # r is a response object.
quotes = pd.DataFrame.from_records(r.json())  # fetches dataset
quotes[0] = pd.to_datetime(quotes[0].str[:-3], format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')  

#Naming columns
quotes.columns = ["Date","Open","High",'Low',"Close", "Vol"]

#Converting dates column to float values
quotes['Date'] = quotes['Date'].map(mdates.date2num)

#Making plot
fig = plt.figure()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (0,0), rowspan=6, colspan=1)

#Converts raw mdate numbers to dates
ax1.xaxis_date()
plt.xlabel("Date")
print(quotes)


#Making candlestick plot
candlestick_ohlc, (ax1,quotes.values,width=1,colorup='g',colordown='k',
alpha=0.75)

plt.show()
```

I'm trying to plot a candlestick chart from json data provided by Huobi but I can't sort the dates out & the plot looks horrible. Can you explain in fairly simple terms that a novice might understand what I am doing wrong please? This is my code ....

Thx, in advance`

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `fig.autofmt_xdate()` at some point after calling the candlestick function; this will make the dates look nicer.

Concerning the plot itself, you may decide to make the bars a bit smaller, `width=0.01`, such that they won't overlap.

You may then also decide to zoom in a bit, to actually see what's going on in the chart, either interactively, or programmatically,

```
ax1.set_xlim(dt.datetime(2017,04,17,8),dt.datetime(2017,04,18,0))
```

Comment: Thx. I have discovered that the candlesticks display correctly if I change from 15min data to day data by altering the line dataLink ='http://api.huobi.com/staticmarket/btc_kline_015_json.js' to dataLink ='http://api.huobi.com/staticmarket/btc_kline_100_json.js'

Comment: Actually, it seems that altering 'http://api.huobi.com/staticmarket/btc_kline_015_json.js' to get different period & length parameters solves this...I think

Answer (score 0):

This boiled down to a question of how wide to make the candlesticks given the granularity of the data as determined by the period & length parameters of the json feed. You just have to fiddle around with the width parameter in  candlestick_ohlc() until the graph looks right...